# Modifying POST requests through Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to implement a Google Chrome extension to modify POST requests. In particular I would like to add some parameter at the "accept: " field. 
I tried to search on the Google Chrome API but I couldn't find anything useful. The only thing that was mentioned was to use the (not experimental anymore) WebRequest API.

I also tried something like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    details.requestHeaders['Accept'] = details.requestHeaders['Accept'] + "+mystuff";
    console.log(details.requestHeaders['Accept']);
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {},
  ["blocking"]);
```

That is something modified from the Google Chrome API, but I get the following error: `"Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'urls': Property is required."` on `extensions/schema_generated_bindings.js:67`.

Since I'm pretty new to this, I'm almost sure I'm going some very naive error here. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/beta/webRequest.html#type-RequestFilter) specify that you must provide a `url` value in the `RequestFilter`.

Something like this should work

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details){...},
  { urls: ['http://example.com'] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, does this mean that I cannot do this for EVERY website? I would like to do that.

Comment: You should try `*://*` then. And remember to set good permissions in the manifest (everything is in the docs, abraham provided the link).

Comment: You can provide an array of match patterns and the match patterns are documented: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/beta/match_patterns.html

Comment: @KonradDzwinel, Careful, If the scheme is *, then it matches either http or https, but not file, or ftp.